# Get path to original python executable (not the virtualenv)

Tags: python, virtualenv

Inside a virtualenv, `sys.executable` gives `/path/to/venv/bin/python`. How do I get the path of the python that the virtualenv was created from, such as `/usr/bin/python3`?

For example,

```
$ cd /tmp
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /tmp/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /tmp/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
$ venv/bin/python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'
/tmp/venv/bin/python
```

The answer that I *want* is `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: It **is** `/path/to/venv/bin/python`.

Comment: The path you say you want is **not** the "real python executable" or "the python that the virtualenv uses". Your desires are inconsistent with themselves.

Comment: Why is it so easy to pedantically disagree, rather than to help?

Comment: It's not pedantry. Without further clarification, it is unclear whether the path the questioner really needs is `/usr/bin/python3`, `/tmp/venv/bin/python`, or `/tmp/venv/bin/python3`. Answering the question in its current state is questionably useful, and more likely to be misleading than helpful to future readers.

Comment: @user2357112 I sure would appreciate some clarification: what is the distinction between the "real python executable" and the "actual Python installation"?

Comment: @Hatshepsut: When running your virtualenv's Python, you are not actually using `/usr/bin/python3`. `/usr/bin/python3` is not involved in any way. I think you could delete that file and still use your virtualenv (though I haven't tested it, and it'd be a really bad idea to delete that file either way). Virtualenv setup creates a new executable at `/tmp/venv/bin/python3`, and the virtualenv uses that executable.

Comment: @user2357112 So an accurate title would be the "original" executable?

Comment: "Original executable" would be an accurate description of `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @user2357112 I've edited the title accordingly. Hopefully it's now accurate and clear.

Comment: @Hatshepsut, Did you find an answer? I understand what you mean and would like to know as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a virtualenv, `sys.real_prefix` is the directory of the actual Python installation being used by the virtualenv.
Other variables worth checking are `sys.base_prefix` and `sys.base_exec_prefix`.
Example code to run in virtualenv:

```
import sys
print(sys.base_prefix)
```

Comment: Is there a cross-platform way to get the python executable out of that directory? For example, my `sys.real_prefix` is `/usr`. So I could `os.path.join(sys.real_prefix, ...)` but IIRC it'll use `Scripts` or `bin` depending on the platform?

Comment: @Hatshepsut: That pathlib snippet isn't as reliable as you're thinking. There's no guarantee the Python executable is going to be under that path. (It wasn't on two systems I just checked, one Windows, one Linux.) ...and I see you've already deleted the comment.

Comment: @Hatshepsut `virtualenv` itself uses hard-coded platform-specific paths. `sysconfig` has no entry specifically for Python executable. So no cross-platform way AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `python -m sysconfig` this will output the system configuration to the terminal. There you can see the `BINDIR` variable.

Therefore you can programatically get this path as well as compute the executable path from within python with:

```py
import sysconfig
from pathlib import Path


bin_dir = sysconfig.get_config_var("BINDIR")
executable_path = Path(bin_dir, "python")
```